How to install nginx and passenger on ubuntu 24.04 noble release
I need some assistance. I am currently deploying a Ruby on Rails application to a DigitalOcean droplet using Capistrano and Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat). I'm following Chris Oliver's guide from GoRails here
The issue arises when I attempt to install Nginx and Passenger. When I enter the following command:
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger $(lsb_release -cs) main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'

I receive this error in the console:
E: The repository 'https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger noble Release' does not have a Release file.

However, if I set up a new server with a different version of Ubuntu, such as 20.04 (Focal Fossa), everything works fine. Has there been a change that I need to be aware of for Ubuntu 24.04? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Passenger do not provide yet a repo for Ubuntu 24.04 (noble):
https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/dists/
So I believe we have these options:

Use passenger in standalone mode behind an nginx reverse proxy;
Install it recompiling nginx;
Use some older distro;
Wait for an official apt repo;


I used ubuntu 20.04 focal release. But thanks

Passenger for noble was released on July 29.

@mutebigodfrey From your output above, you are using 24.04 Noble not 22.04.  Your entire question also states 24.04.

@climatebrad thanks, then i will be able to solve it
